# Hiding "All Site Content" for specific user groups in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, enterprise

I'm new to SharePoint and my company is running SharePoint 2010 Enterprise.  I've taken over this system.

One requirement is to hide the "All Site Content" for certain user groups.  I have some workflows created so when I hide it using this method [sharepoint-2010-how-to-hide-the-view-all-site-content-link-from-the-browser](http://blogs.interfacett.com/sharepoint-2010-how-to-hide-the-view-all-site-content-link-from-the-browser)

I lose a field call My Submissions to forms users submit.  I don't want people to go into All Site Content and see other people form submission due to confidentiality but I want them to see and edit their own forms.

Is this possible?

Curtis

Answer (score 3):

In all site content, user can only see items and list that they have at least limited read permission level. If they don't - they won't see the lists/items. If you have a structure where you hide rather than ban users, your entire permission setting is dead wrong.

They will eventually find out that they can browse to http://siteCollectionURL/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx anyway if they are persistent enough.

Comment: I came across this and it worked for me - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140714173618-36740435-sharepoint-hide-all-site-content-link-for-non-admin-users